# What's the fastest way to draw to a HWND on modern Windows?

Tags: windows, drawing, 2d, pixel

When I last did this you would use DirectDraw to blit to a hardware surface, or even directly map it and draw directly.

What is the recommended method to do this today? Use Direct3D 10/11 and do the same?

Edit: To clarify my question, I want to do some software rasterization and therefore need a fast way to blit pixel data directly to the display.

Comment: Did you try GIL? It's pretty fast for ImageProcessing. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990.aspx) which is meant for desktop applications these days. Quote:

> **Purpose**
>
> Direct2D is a hardware-accelerated, immediate-mode, 2-D graphics API
>   that provides high performance and high-quality rendering for 2-D
>   geometry, bitmaps, and text. The Direct2D API is designed to
>   interoperate well with GDI, GDI+, and Direct3D.

Requirements: Vista and higher as well as the respective server versions (if that is needed).

Comment: D2D is primarily used to draw vector graphics. There are bitmap functions, but they are certainly not a direct path to the VRAM.

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion? If the drivers support it (which they have to in order to get certified), it'll be a direct way. Or what am I missing here? I didn't realize vector graphics were the primary target, I thought fast composition was the primary target for D2D. Frankly it's not clear to me what you're looking for then :)

Comment: Direct2D first goes through texture memory and then draws via rasterizing. It's basically a wrapper around Direct3D.

Comment: @AxelGneiting: These days, with Windows composition system that allows the Aero themes, I don't think it is a good idea to do what you are looking to do. I think that you should find the fastest way to the texture memory that is under your app control, not to the entire screen memory.

Comment: The fastest way is still to draw directly to the buffer that gets drawn to the screen, either by compositor blitting it or by just buffer flipping in case of a full screen application.